# Kotlin secondary constructor with generic type

Tags: kotlin

In java

I can achieve two constructors like

```
public TargetTitleEntryController() { }

public <T extends Controller & TargetTitleEntryControllerListener> TargetTitleEntryController(T targetController) {
        setTargetController(targetController);
}
```

I want to convert it to Kotlin

```
class TargetTitleEntryController ()
```

with the secondary constructor. I don't know how to declare with generic type like Java counterpart.

Answer (score 9):

There is no intersection types in Kotlin (sad)

But there is [Generic constraints](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generic-constraints) (hope)

But [Generic constraints](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generic-constraints) not applicable in the secondary constructor (sad)

But you can simulate secondary constructor in a companion object using [Invoke operator overloading](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#invoke) (workaround):

```
class TargetTitleEntryController {

    // ...

    companion object {

        operator fun <T> invoke(targetController: T): TargetTitleEntryController
                where T : Controller,
                      T : TargetTitleEntryControllerListener {
            return TargetTitleEntryController().apply {
                setTargetController(targetController)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example where you specify a Type `T` which implements two interfaces (`CharSequence`, `Runnable`):

```
class Person<T>(val name: String) where T : CharSequence, T : Runnable {
    constructor(name: String, parent: T) : this(name) {
    }
}
```

So actually something like this should work:

```
class TargetTitleEntryController<T> () where T : Controller, T : TargetTitleEntryControllerListener {
    constructor(targetController: T) : this() {
    }
}
```

Comment: This is different from the OP's example, where the generic on the constructor isn't attached to a type parameter on the class.

Comment: @KenZira I am not aware of any possible way to attach a type to a secondary constructor in Kotlin without using the workaround above.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :)

```
class TargetTitleEntryController <T>() : Controller() where T: Controller, T: TargetTitleEntryControllerListener<T> {

 constructor(target: T) : this() {
        targetController = target
    }
}
```

you can implement it in your parent controller like this:

```
class TargetDisplayController : Controller(), TargetTitleEntryControllerListener<TargetDisplayController> {

  var targetTitleEntryController = TargetTitleEntryController(this)

  override fun onTitlePicked(String option) {

  }

  override fun onAttach(view: View) {
  // push controller here
  }
}
```

Comment: the implementation of  `setTargetController(targetController);` in your questions is 

`targetController = target` in my answer